# what books to read to quickly understand adiabatic approximation

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, probability-distributions, approximation-theory

Hi group, I'm a theoretical ecologist with fairly adequate training in applied math (ODE, linear algebra, applied probability, some PDEs). In my current work, I've encountered the use of adiabatic approximation to a joint probability distribution of two ever-fluctuating spatial variables. A search on the web shows that this method is primarily found in thermodynamics, a field I'm wholly ignorant of. Is there any document/textbook one would recommend that can explain the technique to me given my background? Of course, it'd also be fantastic if someone can clarify the concept for me here on the board.

THANKS!

Comment: The book Dynamic Models in Biology, by Ellner and Guckenheimer might be useful, since it discusses processes where two variables have different time scales. I don't know whether there is any probability in it.

Comment: Been meaning to read that for awhile and now there's more reason to. Thanks for the pointer!